# error in printing in iOS 10

Tags: ios, printing, swift3, ios10

I have a project that I am converting to swift 3. In my printing code, which has been working in swift 2.3 and iOS 9, I have the following lines:

```
    func completionFunc(_: UIPrintInteractionController, _: Bool, _: NSError? ){
        // some action
    }


    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        printController.present( animated: true, completionHandler: completionFunc )
    }
```

now I am getting the following error:

```
error: cannot convert value of type '(UIPrintInteractionController, Bool, NSError?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler?'
            printController.present( animated: true, completionHandler: completionFunc )
                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

From the documentation the definition of UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler is:

```
typealias UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler = (UIPrintInteractionController, Bool, Error?) -> Void
```

so I can not understand the error that has just appeared when trying to migrate the code to swift 3.

Thanks

Reza

Comment: In `completionFunc` replace `NSError`with `Error` thats it.

Comment: thanks Nirav D, that solved the issue